# File appears in destination even though upload request timed out

Tags: c#, sharepoint, httpwebrequest

Given the following code;

```
public static void Upload(Uri target, Stream content)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(target);
    request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Put;
    request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

    using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        content.CopyTo(requestStream);
    }

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {

    }
}
```

I am seeing results that I wasn't expecting in a particular scenario.

The target of my upload request is a SharePoint system, and if I upload a file large enough to cause the request to time out, then a `WebException` is thrown (as expected) with the message "The operation timed out". All good so far.

The weird thing is that if I re-run the same code (even in a fresh process), then after it fails again with another time-out, the file actually appears in the destination. It doesn't appear to be corrupted or partially uploaded either, as I can download it and it seems fully intact.

Is there something else I should be specifying when creating my request that will prevent this from occurring? I know I can just work around this by doing a HEAD only request in the event of a time-out to verify that the file actually made it up, but I'd prefer something a bit more robust if possible.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could try to modify the web config file.

`<httpRuntime executionTimeout="1200" maxRequestLength="2097151" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="100" />`

That is my site web config httpRuntime. You could maybe modify the execution timeout.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The time out isn't really the issue though - it's totally valid that the upload failed. It's just the behaviour where an exception is thrown even though the upload is successful that is causing me a problem.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem, did you ever resolve this? If you did how did you go about it?

Answer (score 0):

The best way - use Sharepoint web interface.

In Central Administration, in Application Management, click Manage web applications.
Select the application (for example, SharePoint - 80).
On the Web Applications ribbon, click the down arrow on the General Settings button.
Click General Settings.
Scroll to Maximum Upload Size.
Set the property to the same number as the Maximum Workbook Size in Excel Services.
Click OK.